# How Can i send the email from the MVC4 to my gmail without using my password?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my Methode in Contactus controller.

```
  [HttpPost]
  public string Sendemail(string username, string useremail, string usermobile)            
     {
        var success = "success";
        var fromemail = useremail;
        var toemail = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["email"];
        var password = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];            
        var body = userdescription;
        var mobile = usermobile;
        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(toemail, password)//here i dont want to   speciefie my pasword      
         // Credentials=new NetworkCredential()
        };
        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromemail, toemail)
        {
            Body = body
        }) { smtp.Send(message); }
        return success.ToString();
    }
```

In My WebConfig File i have specified my username and password and if i try to send to mail its working fine but i am not supposee to speciefie the password in we.config file i need to only speciefie the email not password...

Here IS My Webconfig Code...

```
   <appSettings>  
    <add key="email" value="chandru@yadnom.com"/>
    <add key="password" value="xxxxxxxxx"/>
 </appSettings>
```

If i do like means its workingbut i dont want to specifie my password in web.config also 
i want to speciefie only the email address..

So help me how can i do this..

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: You can't do that. You can, however, encrypt your web.config.

Comment: You can even encrypt a single section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `smtp.gmail.com` without authentication, this is a google policy.

To get around this issue you could:

- encrypt your password in the configuration file (as suggested by bendataclear)
- use a SMTP server that does not require authentication